# Node.js minimist security issue even with v1.2.5

Tags: node.js, express, security, npm, minimist

After installing express-handlebars and running "npm audit", I'm getting a "low severity vulnerability" warning for minimist. npm says: "Patched in >=0.2.1 <1.0.0 || >=1.2.3"

https://npmjs.com/advisories/1179

So I upgraded to minimist v1.2.5 but I'm still getting the security warning.

- Windows 10 pro
- node:      v13.11.0
- npm:       v6.14.3
- express:   v4.17.1
- express-handlebars: v4.7.3
- minimist:  v1.2.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a known issue at the moment:

- https://github.com/substack/minimist/issues/145
- https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8663

Answer (score 0):

```js
 "@jimp/core": {
      "version": "0.8.5",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@jimp/core/-/core-0.8.5.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-Jto1IdL5HYg7uE15rpQjK6dfZJ6d6gRjUsVCPW50nIfXgWizaTibFEov90W9Bj+irwKrX2ntG3e3pZUyOC0COg==",
      "requires": {
        "@jimp/utils": "^0.8.5",
        "any-base": "^1.1.0",
        "buffer": "^5.2.0",
        "core-js": "^2.5.7",
        "exif-parser": "^0.1.12",
        "file-type": "^9.0.0",
        "load-bmfont": "^1.3.1",
        "mkdirp": "0.5.1",
        "phin": "^2.9.1",
        "pixelmatch": "^4.0.2",
        "tinycolor2": "^1.4.1"
      },
      "dependencies": {
        "file-type": {
          "version": "9.0.0",
          "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/file-type/-/file-type-9.0.0.tgz",
          "integrity": "sha512-Qe/5NJrgIOlwijpq3B7BEpzPFcgzggOTagZmkXQY4LA6bsXKTUstK7Wp12lEJ/mLKTpvIZxmIuRcLYWT6ov9lw=="
        },
        "mkdirp": {
          "version": "0.5.1",
          "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/mkdirp/-/mkdirp-0.5.1.tgz",
          "integrity": "sha1-MAV0OOrGz3+MR2fzhkjWaX11yQM=",
          "requires": {
            "minimist": "^0.0.8"
          },
          "dependencies": {
            "minimist": {
              "version": "^0.0.8",
              "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/minimist/-/minimist-0.0.8.tgz",
              "integrity": "sha1-hX/Kv8M5fSYluCKCYuhqp6ARsF0="
            }
          }
        }
```

[Upgrade the minimist in the npm and follow the below steps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0B0bq.png)

**Don't run above snippet**

Check the highlighted image @ https://i.stack.imgur.com/0B0bq.png

I solved mine while going through all the minimist on my package-lock.json file

In my own case **mkdir** was requiring minimist.

The minimist was degraded and it's required, so i went on adding "^" (as indicated in the attached code) to the version of the minimist for both file requiring minimist. then the dependencies requiring minimist can go for the latest version of minimist other than the 0.0.8 version of minimist